# Addslashes puts a slash into the database

Tags: php

I'm guessing that there is a simple explanation for this but I can find it anywhere.  Please know that this is not a security issue as I only have this form on the web when I am adding music to my DJ database.  When I finish, I take the form down.  I just need to get around the issue of apostrophe in either the Artist name or Song Title name.  This is the code I have:

```
$cleana= addslashes($artist);

$cleant= addslashes($title);

$artist=$cleana;

$title=$cleant;
```

My problem is that it adds 3 \'s to the string and when it writes to the database there is a \ in the entry.  These are the only two fields that could possibly have an ' in them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 3 \'s means that the string is already escaped because of `magic_quotes` so you probably don't need to escape it... Another way (to keep your head relaxed and make sure all is well escaped) is using `stripslases` first, then addslashes. But the link @quentin shared is the best way to go although you say security isn't your concern....

Comment: Get a recent PHP version and you get rid of this. This smells like Magic Quotes, you find it explained in the PHP Manual in full length: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php - You perhaps just want to disable it. And as others have said, you're doing database operations wrong here in case of input encoding.

Comment: @CodeBird thanks so much.  Not just for the help but also for accepting that I don't need to be super secure.  I'm a newbie hack and I assure you I always read everything I can find in Google and on here that might solve an issue before I ask.  And most of the "already answered" links are beyond my scope of understanding.  This is just a list of my songs and when I finish with additions I remove the page from the web and copy the DB from the web server to my computer.  So I just needed to get by the ' issue and the error message.

Comment: @CodeBird I went to the INI file on the server and disabled magic_quotes but that didn't solve the issue.  BUT I tried the stripslashes as you suggested and for whatever reason it solved the problem.  I can now get back to my data entry thanks to your help to a newbie.

Comment: server should be restarted after changing the main php.ini, and some hosting providers doesn't let you have your own php.ini. so putting anything there won't help. `stripslashes` helped because it removed the \'s added by `magic_quotes`